# How to free an int array from a function in the Main function

Tags: c

I understand how the allocation of `malloc` works and I can free the variable inside the function where the allocation of bytes is happening. But when I try to free it in the Main Function I'm unable to free it. I have tried multiple ways but I can't free it. Also I would appreciate an explanation of free works in dis-allocating memory in C.

```
void printArray(int arr[], int count)
{
     printf("Values stored in the array are:");
     // for loop that goes through printing every value in the array.
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      printf("[%d]", arr[i]);
    }
}

//function that takes in a size as parameter and creates an array of that size 
// and prints it.
void evenOdd(int asize){
int* array = (int*)malloc(asize*sizeof(int));
    int position;
    // loop that goes through every position in the array and decides if a 0 or 
    // 1 is assigned.
    for(position = 0; position < asize;position++){
       if(position%2 == 0){
        array[position] = 0;
       }else{
        array[position] = 1;
       }
    }
    printArray(array,asize);
}

int main(void) {
    evenOdd(10);
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Return it from that function to the `main` function, then you can free it there (though I really can't see the point in doing that).

Comment: Why not to free it *in* the function?

Comment: `array` is not in the scope of `main`. . this won't compile

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Allocating the array in the heap to simply "*print*" it, is not a use case. You can directly print the values. If you, express your real situation in a simpler program i.e. a [mcve], then perhaps we can give you some advice. Normally, you allocate the array on the heap and return it ... use it, and then free it. Keeping a pointer to it as long as you need it, and freeing it when your done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either free the memory in `evenOdd` after the `printArray` or return the pointer, so that the calling function can free it:

```
int *evenOdd(int asize){
    int* array = malloc(asize * sizeof *array);
    if(array == NULL)
        return 0;

    int position;
    // loop that goes through every position in the array and decides if a 0 or 
    // 1 is assigned.
    for(position = 0; position < asize;position++){
       if(position%2 == 0){
        array[position] = 0;
       }else{
        array[position] = 1;
       }
    }
    printArray(array,asize);

    return array;
}

int main(void) {
    int *array = evenOdd(10);
    if(array == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

> I understand how the allocation of `malloc` works and I can free the variable inside the function

Note that you don't free variables, you free the memory pointed to by a pointer.
That's a fine distinction, because of this you can allocate memory in a function
and free it in a different function, as long as your program "remembers" the
address that `malloc`/`realloc`/`calloc` returned. You achieve this by returning the
allocated pointer like in the code above. Another way is by passing a double
pointer:

```
void bar(int **arr, size_t size)
{
    if(arr == NULL)
        return;

    *arr = malloc(size * sizeof **arr);

    if(arr == NULL)
        return;

    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        (*arr)[i] = i % 2;
}

void foo()
{

    int *arr = NULL;
    bar(&arr, 10);

    if(arr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "not enough memory\n");
        return;
    }

    free(arr);
}
```

Comment: Can we free an array in a different function from where it was allocated?

Comment: @Royi yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up the formatting of your code to make it more legible (below).  As you have it written, this will not compile.  When you write your questions, be specific about what won't work/happen and any errors you receive. "The code won't compile and gives X as an error", not "I'm unable to free it"

In this case, the pointer to your array exists only within the evenOdd function and is inaccessible/not within the scope of the main function. When you try to use it in the main function, main has no idea what "array" is.

I would suggest that you read up on the C language, with a particular focus on **variable scope**. There are a number of ways to solve this including returning the pointer, passing a pointer into evenOdd and then assigning memory to it, or making the pointer global. Any C reference will give a basic explanation, and you will be better off getting a basic grasp of the language before trying to proceed in the dark.

```
void printArray(int arr[], int count)
{
    printf("Values stored in the array are:");
    // for loop that goes through printing every value in the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
         printf("[%d]", arr[i]);
    }
}

//function that takes in a size as parameter and creates an array of that size and prints it.
void evenOdd(int asize){
    int* array = (int*)malloc(asize*sizeof(int));
    int position;

    // loop that goes through every position in the array and decides if a 0 or 1 is assigned.
    for(position = 0; position < asize;position++){
        if(position%2 == 0){
            array[position] = 0;
        }else{
            array[position] = 1;
        }
    }
 printArray(array,asize);
}

int main(void) {
    evenOdd(10);
    free(array); //array doesn't exist inside main, this won't compile

    return 0;
}
```